Bad Low-quality Answers reviews, July 2024 edition
Continuing the trend of users making bad reviews on this site... (I'm pretty sure it's a lot of the same users from then too...) This has once again become a problem. Reviewing my disputed "Not an Answer" flags, these are the bad review links for reference:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/212955
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/212937
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/212911
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/212913
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/212869
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/212857
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/212849
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/212848
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/212845
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/212844
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/212660
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/212644
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/212648
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/212620
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/212254
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/211788
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/211580

Some of these are link-only, some are blatantly just questions. Of these bad reviews, here are the accuracy rates per user with errors:



User id
wrong/total reviews
accuracy%




85907
10/12
17%


44220
9/12
25%


82140
8/9
11%


48253
8/8
0%


82670
2/2
0%


50161
1/2
50%


77673
1/1
0%


76504
1/1
0%



These accuracies are astonishingly low. If users are not able to distinguish what is or is not an answer, they should not be reviewing. We don't need more reviews. We need more accurate reviews to keep the site clean.

I agree that every one of these I have checked is a delete-worthy, link-only answer.

Thanks for taking the time to make the list. I did the cleanup

@Marius Thank you. I appreciate the response.
